# Upgrading EPI5 to EPI6 Assembly newer error

Tags: upgrade, episerver

Im getting an error when upgrading EPI 5.2 to EPI 6.0. 
The error message is in swedish but it enterprate it like the assemblies are newer than the installer, so i downloaded a new version of the installer (deployment center) but i got the same message.

```
” An unhandled error has occured:
Det går inte att läsa in filen eller sammansättningen C:\EPiServer\Sites\Uppgra
deraSiteName\SiteName.Web\bin\Sitename.Web.dll eller ett av dess beroenden. Den hä
r sammansättningen har skapats med ett program av en senare version än det aktu
ella inlästa programmet och kan därför inte läsas in.
When executing

At C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\Framework\6.0.318.113\Install\System Script
s\Install Site (SqlServer).ps1:147 char:27
+           Add-EPiAssemblyRedirect <<<<  -TargetFilePath $targetWebConfigPath -Source
AssemblyPath  $file.FullName

=
Get-EPiIsBulkInstalling

At C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\Framework\6.0.318.113\Install\System Scripts\Install Site (SqlServer).ps1:147 char:27
+           Add-EPiAssemblyRedirect <<<<  -TargetFilePath $targetWebConfigPath -SourceAssemblyPath  $file.FullName
System.BadImageFormatException: Det går inte att läsa in filen eller sammansättningen C:\EPiServer\Sites\UppgraderaSiteName\SiteName.Web\bin\SiteName.Web.dll eller ett av dess beroenden. Den här sammansättningen har skapats med ett program av en senare version än det aktuella inlästa programmet och kan därför inte läsas in.
Filnamn: C:\EPiServer\Sites\SiteName\SiteName.Web\bin\SiteName.Web.dll
   vid System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s)
   vid System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)
   vid EPiServer.Install.Xml.Installers.AddAssemblyRedirectInstaller.Install(IDictionary savedState)
   vid EPiServer.Install.InstallationManager.Install(Installer installer)
   vid EPiServer.Install.Xml.XmlInstallationManager.AddAssemblyRedirect(String targetFilePath, String assemblyFilePath, String oldVersion)
   vid EPiServer.Install.Xml.Cmdlets.AddAssemblyRedirectCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   vid System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
   vid System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running Deployment Center on the wrong .NET Framework version.

Check this link if site is built against 4.0:
http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Paul-Smith/Dates1/2011/3/Upgrading-CMS-6-R1-sites-compiled-against-NET-40/

For the record says to add this to your Deployment Center config:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

The Deployment Center configuration file can be found at the following path on the target machine:

{Program Files}\EPiServer\Shared\Install\EPiServerInstall.exe.config